# Flink batching Sink

Tags: batch-processing, apache-flink, flink-streaming, accumulo

I'm trying to use flink in both a streaming and batch way, to add a lot of data into Accumulo (A few million a minute). I want to batch up records before sending them to Accumulo. 
I ingest data either from a directory or via kafka, convert the data using a flatmap and then pass to a RichSinkFunction, which adds the data to a collection.

With the streaming data, batching seems ok, in that I can add the records to a collection of fixed size which get sent to accumulo once the batch threshold is reached. But for the batch data which is finite, I'm struggling to find a good approach to batching as it would require a flush time out in case there is no further data within a specified time.
There doesn't seem to be an Accumulo connector unlike for Elastic search or other alternative sinks.

I thought about using a Process Function with a trigger for batch size and time interval, but this requires a keyed window. I didn't want to go down the keyed route as data looks to be very skewed, in that some keys would have a tonne of records and some would have very few. If I don't use a windowed approach, then I understand that the operator won't be parallel.  I was hoping to lazily batch, so each sink only cares about numbers or an interval of time.

Has anybody got any pointers on how best to address this?

Comment: I don't know anything about Flink, but a lot of frameworks support MapReduce OutputFormat sinks, and Accumulo has some OutputFormats. Maybe that will work for you?

Answer (score 4):

You can access timers in a sink by implementing `ProcessingTimeCallback`. For an example, look at the [`BucketingSink`](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/release-1.6/flink-connectors/flink-connector-filesystem/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/fs/bucketing/BucketingSink.java#L164) -- its [open](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/release-1.6/flink-connectors/flink-connector-filesystem/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/fs/bucketing/BucketingSink.java#L405) and [onProcessingTime](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/release-1.6/flink-connectors/flink-connector-filesystem/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/fs/bucketing/BucketingSink.java#L503) methods should get you started.

Comment: you saved my time! I look for many information but get nothing。Add, now`BucketingSink` is deprected, you can refer to [StreamingFileSink](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-streaming-java/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/functions/sink/filesystem/StreamingFileSink.java) instead. KeyWord: flink, sink, timer, bacth, cache